# Too many lines on the page and too many characters in the lines

Tags: conversion, msword

I have converted a word document to Tex using Word2Tex.  With the tex document in 12 point, the corresponding pdf document has 38 lines on each page, and about 77 characters per line.  However, I would prefer it if there were fewer lines on each page and fewer characters in each line.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could change the margins.  `\usepackage[margin = 2in]{geometry}`  This would give you a `2in` margin all around so less characters could fit across and lines on the page.

Comment: I think @dustin meant `\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}`. Check the [documentation of **`geometry`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/geometry).

Comment: @henrique I noticed I forgot `{geometry}` when I came back from heating up my chicken curry.

Comment: Which document class do you use? With KOMA-Script you can use the class option DIV=X, and try 6, 12 or 18 for X.

Answer (score 1):

Play with this MWE changing the font size (from `10pt` to `11pt` or `12pt` only, if you need another font sizes see the package `anyfontsize` or use the `extsizes` or `KOMA-Script` classes) as well as margins (values of the `geometry` package) and line spacing value of `1.3`.

The package `lipsum` and `\lipsum` commands are to obtain dummy text and check the results, as well as the package `lineno` and `\linenumbers` to quickly see the changes in the number of lines. You can delete all of this when you find the desired format and put your text in the document.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3} 
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```